# Moodle customized login page for a specific course

Tags: php, moodle

It is great that [moodle](/questions/tagged/moodle) enables having a specific course using theme different than the rest of the site. But now when someone receives a link for a content within a course with specific theme set, Moodle first redirects him to login page which is in global theme, and then redirects him to the course with specific theme. And this change of themes is not really convenient. I would like to have that login page also in global theme.

After research, I figured out that there is no solution available, and that I'll need to tweak the code.

I think the possible solution is to use `$SESSION->wantsurl`, detect when the url is heading to the course with a specific theme and then serve different login page.

But the problem is lack of documentation, I really cannot find these concepts explained. I don't know in which file inside the Moodle files I should add this exception, where to put and how to duplicate new login page. I think I could manage writing the code in php.

Moodle version is 2.8.3.

Thank you if you can provide me with any guidelines and references for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around by adding the required theme to the url.

First add this to your `config.php`

```
$CFG->allowthemechangeonurl = true;
```

Then add this to any link

http://www.yourmoodlesite.com/?theme=yourthemename

For reference :

https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Theme_settings#Allow_theme_changes_in_the_URL

UPDATE : you could use this before any output.

```
$PAGE->force_theme($themename);
```

Then like you say, check $SESSION->wantsurl to see if its a course page then get the course theme.

Comment: I think this is not a solution. Firstly there are so many links that user can receive, and I'm not sure how to add that to every link inside specific course... Another problem is that user needs to have privileges to change the theme, and the change of theme is permanent. So actually the main theme would be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I like this solution in update... But I'm not sure how to implement it. Can you tell me in which file should I put this code. I tried to include it into \themename\layout\login.php but it prompts me with an error:  "Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: The theme has already been set up for this page ready for output. Therefore, you can no longer change the theme, or anything that might affect what the current theme is, for example, the course."

Comment: Oh add a it near the top of login/index.php

Comment: Unfortunately the same error persists... So I guess that's not the right place.

Comment: I just realized that even if I manage a way around this problem with changing the theme, there is no way I can say that specific content is part of one course. The url does not contain information specific to the course, instead it calls modules inside them by their specific ids.